# PyCharm's add source directory equivalent in standalone mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package, pycharm

I have created python project in `PyCharm` and recreated maven directory structure, I used when was programming in `Java`.

I.e. in project directory I have created `src` subdirecotry, there `main` subdirectory and there `python` subdirectory.

In `PyCharm` I was able to right-click `python`, then `Mark Directory As... -> Sources Root`

This made all modules and files visible from scripts in root directory.

However, when running script from root directory from command line it complains

```
$ python3 train.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mydataset import mymodel
ImportError: No module named 'mydataset'
```

How to fix?

I prefer not to put path addition code into each script.

**UPDATE**

Adding `__init__.py` file to root project directory with the following code

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "src/main/python")
```

didn't help

Comment: Same problem for me, not like in your specific case (Java, Source folder, etc..) but in plain Python, even if put init.py file in folders... Still `No module named` error.